# Execute software remote installation using JSCH

Tags: java, shell, ssh, jsch

Currently, I'm writing some software that is able to execute a remote installation via SSH (using JSCH as SSH library and Java as a programming language).
To do this I have implemented:

- Step 1: Create a SSH connection to remote host (no problem)
- Step 2: Copy of my installation source files from origin to the destination host (no problem)
- Step 3: Execute the installation scripts (within the installation kit) that, during installation, required some user inputs (for example passwords, parameters ...) (this is my problem)

What I want is to show dynamically the output of installation (shell output) and then show a popup to the user when the installation require a user input.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is to question your whole approach: are you sure that you want to re-invent the wheel?

To satisfy your requirement, you actually have to fetch "console content" from your remote server; somehow display it to your local user; and sent that information back to write it to the remote console. Probably doable, but not exactly an easy undertaking.

And why all that effort? To implement another "configuration management" tool; along with the many others that already exist?

I think you should step back and consider **not doing** all of this yourself. You see, there are a lot of fine tools out there (puppet, chef, salt, ...) that are robust, well documented, used by many people for a long time. Instead of spending your time to mimic some of the functions of such tools; wouldn't it be better to learn about these tools; and use one of them directly?!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your observation is correct, I think is the correct way to not re-invent the wheel...but...is there a java tool that can help me in this way? I've searched with no concrete results

Comment: Well, the key questions are: what exactly is your requirement? And more importantly, why do you think you need "java" on the front end side?

Comment: The requirement is: control a remote script shell execution that require user interaction (the same that an can user do opening a remote terminal). I'm using java because this is an additional require for an existing software.